# How do I auto duck volume of applications in Linux?

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, qt, volume

For myself I'm building a navigation/dashcam/music unit for my motorcycle.
This consists of a Qt application which captures 2 windows from my navigational software and music player.
To do this, I have a script which starts the applications, reads out the window code and starts my Qt program with the codes as arguments, and it captures the applications inside the Qt application.

The audio is routed through bluetooth to my helmet comms device. However, when the navigation software comes with an audio update, the music keeps playing on a normal level. This makes the navigation command barely understandable.

Is there an (easy) way to auto enable ducking so the music application lowers volume/mutes when the nav software speaks?

Thanks in advance!

Dave

Device: raspberry pi 3b+

Comment: Assuming Pulseaudio and sufficiently different audio sources, it's not hard to write a custom application for that, but I don't know of any ready-made one.

Comment: I have read about pulse audio and that one could use environment variables(?). Apart from writing some C++ code and basic bash script, I have no knowledge on how to do this. Most quick tips and links are above my knowledge level, so it's hard to pick it up.

Comment: To my knowledge, one can't use environment variables for that, but if you can edit your question and add a link to what you read, I can have a look at it. If the quick tips are already above your knowledge level, then writing custom code also will be, of course - in that case I you probably can't do it.